# Does Monsieur Hulot have a first name?

Tags: character, comedy

Jacques Tati's iconic character is always called by his last name. At least as long as I have seen (*Monsieur Hulot's holiday*, *Mon Oncle*, *Playtime*). Does anybody know if he was ever called anything else - anywhere?
Thanks.